# How can I calculate the number of buckets in a hash if I know that the distibution will be unequal?

Tags: mysql, performance, hash, hashtable, partitioning

I have the following problem (I will give the actual context bellow):
I have a series of ids (the are of course associated data with these ids but I will give the core problem) 1..up to 500000
Now these are sequentials **but** they "arrive" randomly and some may never "arrive" and others may come frequently in many batches so they are are unequally distributed (what I am referring to when I say arrive I mean as records in the database).
If I create some kind of count of the ids and their appearances how can I find how many what is the proper number of buckets to do a modulo on, so that the buckets are equally filled?

Context of my problem:
I was reading about [hash partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-hash.html)
I think that the basic assumption is that the column values that you hash on are well distributed. But what happens if in a table you can not partition on an column/attribute that is well distributed (because the data are not well distributed e.g. customer id that buy more things than others that buy very few).
So how should this be handled? Should the partition range be small instead? (I mean the modulo part to be small instead of large)

Comment: If you've got already a reasonable amount of data, why don't you test the distribution with a series of `SELECT id_column % @partitions as bucket, COUNT(id_column % @partitions) as cnt GROUP BY (id_column % @partitions)` and different values for the variable `@partitions`?

Comment: @VMai:So `@partitions` is a variable e.g. 4? You mean `GROUP BY 1`? So essentially count how many are that fall in the same bucket irrespective of what are the actual ids?

Comment: Well yes. Use the client of your choice, i.e. phpMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench, ... and execute: `SET @partitions = 4;` followed by the statement from last comment, then simply change 4 to 5, ... and have a look at the distribution.

Comment: @VMai:This is very useful.But in my case I need to group by a date as I want to see this per month and not just for the full table. How could I combine this?

Comment: Did I get this right: You want the row count per month? `SELECT MONTH(your_date), COUNT(*) GROUP BY MONTH(your_date)` should do this. You could use the modulo opration on MONTH(your_date) too, if needed. But then I would recommend only to use 2,3,4,6 :-)

Comment: I mean that I am interested to see the distribution per month.I assume that it would be the same per month but I am not sure.I could use your initial query for a distribution over all data but then I would need to see how they arrive per month since the per month part is the core issue for me

Comment: I misunderstood :-(. I think I write it as an answer :-)

Comment: @VMai:That would be great!Your initial suggestion helps to get an indication of the pattern in the overall data, but it could be that some ids came frequently back in "history" and not any more but if I just aggregate the fact that in the past e.g. 12 months don't show up it will not be shown.So I need to make sure that I have an indicative pattern per month as well to see how they distribute per month

Comment: Do you have any `SELECTs` that demonstrate that `PARTITION BY HASH` benefits you in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the distribution per partition monthly then you could do that with following statements:

```
SET @partitions = 4; 

SELECT
    id_column % @partitions as bucket,
    MONTH(your_date) as month,
    COUNT(*) as cnt
GROUP BY
    month,
    bucket;
```

and play with the value of the variable @partitions. If the timeline spans more than a year, then add just a YEAR column:

```
SET @partitions = 4; 

SELECT
    id_column % @partitions as bucket,
    YEAR(your_date) as year,
    MONTH(your_date) as month,
    COUNT(*) as cnt
GROUP BY
    year,
    month,
    bucket;
```

That's a good method to see how available data will be distributed between the partitions.

Comment: But `your_date` is a date type that spans over many years.This query would put january of all years in the same row, right?

Comment: If you want it by every month in the timespan, no problem, see edit.

Comment: I was wondering why are you using the variable @partitions instead of 4 directly?Is it some sort of convenience that I am unaware?

Comment: Additionally how should I go about testing?Should I test only powers of 2 (i.e. 4,8 etc) or any number?

Comment: @Jim The variable is of no great value here, but I find it easier to modify. I would try simple increment steps in an appropriate range, let's say starting with 4.